# Qt задать текст LineEdit в слоте

Tags: c++, qt

Есть слот `loadValues()`

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
    void loadValues();
};
```

Создан QLineEdit и QPushButton:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
QLineEdit *nameEdit = new QLineEdit();
QPushButton *loadFromFileButton = new QPushButton("Загрузить из файла");
...
connect(loadFromFileButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
SLOT(loadValues()));
}
```

Вопрос в том, как в слоте loadValues() задать текст QLineEdit?

```
void MainWindow::loadValues()
{
   nameEdit.setText("123");
}
```

Ошибка:

> 'nameEdit' was not declared in this scope nameEdit.setText("123");

Comment: setText должен работать. Подозреваю, вы получаете ошибку еще на этапе компиляции. Текст ошибок и в чем проблема нужно писать в вопросе.

Comment: ошибка: 'nameEdit' was not declared in this scope
     nameEdit.setText("123");

Comment: В тексте вопроса сообщения об ошибках должны быть. Далее, у вас проблема с областями видимости nameEdit.

Comment: Я понимаю, что с областями видимости, как разрешить проблему

Comment: Опыт в C/C++ у вас есть? Особенно в плане ООП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nameEdit следует сделать членом класса MainWindow.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLineEdit *nameEdit = {nullptr};
public slots:
    void loadValues();
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    nameEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    QPushButton *loadFromFileButton = new QPushButton("Загрузить из файла", this);
    ...
    connect(loadFromFileButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
    SLOT(loadValues()));
}
```

Аналогично стоит поступить и с остальными компонентами, в том числе и с QPushButton *loadFromFileButton.

**Дополнение:** дочерним объектам (в данном случае виджетам) необходимо указывать родителя, поскольку при удалении последнего обозначенные объекты уничтожены не будут.

Comment: точно.. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для Qt5 могу предложить решение с примением лямбда-функции:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui.setupUi(this); // вы кстати забыли эту строчку

  auto nameEdit = new QLineEdit(this);  // про родителя вы тоже забыли
  auto loadFromFileButton = new QPushButton("Загрузить из файла", this);
  ...
  connect(    loadFromFileButton
            , SIGNAL(clicked())
            , [nameEdit](){nameEdit->setText("1234");}
         );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

А почему-бы не использовать без слота:

```
QString text = lineEdit->toPlainText();
```